# разобрать dwStyle WindowsAPI

Tags: winapi, kotlin

```
    println(WinUser.WINDOWINFO().also { User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowInfo(User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow(), it) }.dwStyle or 0x00C00000)
```

По идее этот код должен проверять стиль окна на наличие строки заголовка (согласно [этой](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-styles) таблице). Но, оно почему-то возвращает какое-то число вместо 0 или 1. Пробовал так-же and (не сильно разбираюсь в разборке такого числа), та же самая ахинея

Comment: Пробовал так-же на окне idea, и на окне проводника (где заголовка нет)

Comment: Я уже далек от Windows development, но если правильно помню, надо AND к стилю применить, чтобы отфильтровать по маске. Получите либо ноль, либо не ноль. OR применяется для установки стиля.